# $|f(x)|\leq M/16(b-a)^2$?

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be twice continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$. Assume that $f(a)=f'(a)=f(b)=f'(b)=0$. $M=\max_{[a,b]}|f''|$. Show that $|f(x)|\leq M/16(b-a)^2$, for any $x\in [a,b]$.

At first glance, we can use Taylor formula on $[a,(a+b)/2]$, but gives the coefficient $1/8$ instead of $1/16$.

$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\int_a^x \int_a^t f''(s)ds dt$$ implies $$|f(x)|\leq M \int_a^x \int_a^t ds dt=\frac{(b-a)^2}{8}.$$

Can we prove $1/16$ as the problem states?

Comment: Aren't you forgetting a factor $2$ in Taylor's approximation?

Comment: @StanTendijck No. This is an integral form...